# Why this output?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have been trying to understand of this following C-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
int count;

int incr(){
 return ++count;
}

int main(){  
   arr[count++]=incr();
   printf("%d %d",count,arr[count]);    
   return 0;
}
```

The program gives **1 2** as [output](http://ideone.com/7lhgB),what I am not gtting is why the value of count is *1* here and not *2* (since there are two increments)?

Comment: You should initialize the count variable;
`count = 0`
otherwise the value will be undefined.

Comment: @Drahakar : Global variables are initialized to their default values. In OP's code count would be initialized to 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of evaluation of operands of  `=` operator is unspecified in `arr[count++]=incr();` and since both the operands are trying to modify the same global variable `count` the result would be different on different compilers depending upon the order of evaluation.

**EDIT**

Actually the behavior is **undefined** (which means anything can happen) because ["the prior value of the variable `count` is not accessed (only) to determine the value to be stored."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: either way, by the `printf` line, the value of `count` should be 2, not 1, though, no?

Comment: No, because it's undefined behaviour it can actually be _anything_. Your compiler decides to make it 1, but there's no guarantee on what it could be

Comment: Yep the value would be undefined since it's I think it's same as `a[i++]= ++i;`

Comment: I don't believe that this is undefined. I sent a PR to GCC about this. See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48814

Answer (score 4):

`incr()` will return either `1` or `2`. It depends on whether the implementation first increments `count` and then calls `incr()`, or whether it first calls `incr()` and then increments `count`.

Please note that this choice does not mean that behavior is undefined. Since before a function is entered, and after a function is left, there is a sequence point at each point, both increments we have here are separated by a sequence point, so that the increment in `main`, if it started to happen before the call, will be finished once entering `incr()`, and if it happens after `incr()` was called, will not have yet started until `incr()` has left.

We have multiple scenarios here:

- First do the increment for `count++`, then call `incr()`. This will write `2` into `arr[0]`.
- First call `incr()`, then do the increment for `count++`. This will write `1` into `arr[1]`.

So, `count` is always `2`, and `arr[count]` is always `3` (it wasn't overwritten). So it should output `2 3`, not `1 2`.

I think that if you do the following, you have more options

```
int main(){  
   arr[++count]=incr();
   printf("%d %d",count,arr[count]);    
   return 0;
}
```

Now, the value read from `++count` can be different than `count+1`, because there is nothing that stops `incr()` to be called after incrementing `count` but before reading it. In this case we have

- First do the increment for `++count`, then call `incr()`, then read from `count`. This will write `2` into `arr[2]`.
- First do the increment for `++count`, then read from `count`, and then call `incr()`. This will write `2` into `arr[1]`.
- First call `incr()`, then do the increment for `++count` and read from it. This will write `1` into `arr[2]`.

In this case, you can either have output `2 2` or `2 1` or `2 3`.